# Why I can use lightGBM and not Catboost on the same dataset?

Tags: python, catboost

I'm doing a competition on Kaggle, I tried LGBM it's working just fine, but when I try Catboost, it's impossible overcome that error. Can anyone help please, thank you. My data is untouch so I don't understand this error

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) 7 grid_search_result = ctb.grid_search(grid, 8 X=X_train, ----> 9 y=Y_train) ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_pool() _catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_pool() _catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_features_order_layout_pool() _catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._set_label_features_order() _catboost.pyx in _catboost.__pyx_fused_cpdef() TypeError: No matching signature found

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    7 grid_search_result = ctb.grid_search(grid,       8    X=X_train,
----> 9 y=Y_train)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in 

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_pool()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_pool()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._init_features_order_layout_pool()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._PoolBase._set_label_features_order()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost.__pyx_fused_cpdef()

TypeError: No matching signature found

Comment: Please provide more context in terms of code used, rather than just the error you received.